# sort Object of keys with conditions

Tags: javascript, sorting, object

I have the below Object

```
Object={
   '11': 1.2317655481421725,
   '12': 1.233489927305401,
   '13': 1.2317655481421725,
   '14': 1.233489927305401,
   '15': 1.205620575126925,
   '16': 1.2600762465738233,
   '17': 1.205620575126925,
   '18': 1.2600762465738233,
   '41': 0.8577882967879851,
   '42': 0.8890249774881712,
   '43': 0.8577882967879851,
   '44': 0.8890249774881712,
   '45': 0.8268651773658509,
   '46': 0.8977620865671874,
   '47': 0.8268651773658509,
   '48': 0.8977620865671874
 }
```

which I need to order by the values according to some conditions

- when the values of the keys are equal, check a flag of each one of the keys that may be either 0 or 1, and sort first the one with flag=1
- in any other case sort all the rest keys by value in descending order

The code I run looks like below

```
keysSorted = Object.keys(Object).sort(function(a,b){

Flag_b=parseInt(Products[Object.keys(Object)[b-1]]['attribute'])
Flag_a=parseInt(Products[Object.keys(Object)[a-1]]['attribute'])
// console.log('key a',Object.keys(Object)[a-1],'Flag_a ', Flag_a, 'key b',Object.keys(Object)[b-1],'Flag_b', Flag_b)

//case equal utilities
if ((Object[b]===Object[a]) && (user.answer===1)){
    key_a=Object.keys(Object)[a-1]
    key_b=Object.keys(Object)[b-1]
    console.log('true equality','key_b',key_b,'Object[b]',Object[b],'key a',key_a,'Object[a]',Object[a])
    console.log('key a',key_a,'Flag_a ', Flag_a, 'key b',key_b,'Flag_b', Flag_b)
    if (Flag_a===1){
        return -1 
    }       
}
if (Object[b]!==Object[a]){
    return (Object[b]-Object[a])
}

})
```

The correct sorting would start with the key values 11 and 13, if flag of key 11 is 0 and flag of key 13 is 1, then sort first `[13,11 ...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [only order](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinaryownpropertykeys) that objects give their properties is such that you can't change it for the object you've shown, because the order for properties with names consisting entirely of digits (within the range 0 to 2³²-1) is *numeric*. So it doesn't matter what you do with that object or another object, the property with the name `"11"` will always come before the property with the name `"42"`.

Trying to put objects in a particular order is usually poor practice even when it's possible (which it is with property names that don't consist entirely of digits).

Instead, use an array of `key`/`value` objects, and sort that.

Comment: So what if the Object is `Object ={
   11: 1.2317655481421725,
   12: 1.233489927305401,
   13: 1.2317655481421725,
   14: 1.233489927305401,
   15: 1.205620575126925,
   16: 1.2600762465738233,
   17: 1.205620575126925,
   18: 1.2600762465738233,
   41: 0.8577882967879851,
   42: 0.8890249774881712,
   43: 0.8577882967879851,
   44: 0.8890249774881712,
   45: 0.8268651773658509,
   46: 0.8977620865671874,
   47: 0.8268651773658509,
   48: 0.8977620865671874
 }` will it be possible then?

Comment: @user2829319 - That object has the same keys. Although you can write an object literal with number literals for the property names, the property keys (loosely, "names") are still strings (they're converted). So `{11: "eleven"}` and `{"11": "eleven"}` create **exactly** the same object. Objects never have numbers as property keys, only strings and Symbols.

Comment: ok, now it's clear. I have used the map function to convert it into key, values array of objects and hopefully will get where I need. As soon as I got it I will update the code above

Comment: @user2829319 - No need to update the question, you've already asked this question and received an answer. If you run into trouble doing the sorting, there are **lots** of answers here about how to sort arrays; but if none of them help you figure it out, post a new question with the array, the rules, and your code that doesn't quite work, and folks will be happy to help.